# How to change the font-color on outlook by css?

Tags: css, fonts, colors, outlook

Why my font color is set to white on outlook, even if I got CSS to overwrite it? With any other email reader (gmail, hotmail, etc), my font-color is ok!

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: Post your code how you set the color in CSS.

Comment: Outlook doesn't like CSS. Use inline styles.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot believe this is still an issue in 2020.

To fix it add this after `<body>` tag:

```
<!--[if mso]>
<style type="text/css">
body, table, td {color: #000000 !important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Of course adjust color value to your needs. You can add some more html tags as well, for example my emails had a lot of `<p>` elements so I appended it to this list.

Comment: this all seems to work if you put this code in the head tag (like a normal style tag).

Comment: I did not test with head tag

Answer (score 1):

Outlook uses the MS-word engine for rendering (barf!). Stylesheets are not supported. **some** inline styles are.

See this handy guide:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: It was the color on my body. My color on my td dosen't overwrite it, I don't know why.

Comment: You need an inline font statement <font style="color:#000000">your text</font>

Comment: You can also check out **[emailology](http://www.emailology.org/)** for some tips and tricks for html emails. Designing those things is like walking back in time 10 years...

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane your solution worked! Thank you!